# Ag-grid firefox onBlur event not working on customEditor

Tags: firefox, ag-grid, react-typescript, ag-grid-react

I have a custom editor and custom renderer and inside that an input text box in react. OnFocus event on the text box is starting the edit by calling the startEditingCell() API. Similarly onBlur event on the text box opens a Modal and based on the option selected, we either save the input by calling stopEditing() or cancel the edit by calling stopEditing(cancel: true). In Chrome, everything is working fine but in Firefox, we are seeing that the onBlur() event itself is not getting triggered. Any idea on how we can implement this onBlur() functionality for FireFox?

onBlur() event to get triggered in Firefox.